# Splitting a data frame by the values from one of the columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I am new to R and we have been given a dataset about flies with column heading such as species and sex. In total there are 111 species. The goal is to know how many males and females are in each species and to have it in a form that can be used for further analysis (t-test).

Ideally I would have one data frame with 3 columns (Species, number of females, number of males). I used the split function which has given me the best result thus far the problem is that I don't know how to do it for 111 species in a reasonable amount of time. I though about using a for loop but am unsure about how I could do that. This is the split code that I used:

```r
data_split <- split(data, data$Species)
data_split
sp1 <- data_split$D_acutila
data.frame(table(sp1$Sex))
```

Comment: Hi Bf2111, welcome. Could you please give a reproducible example? It would make it easier to understand the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple data frame that I believe is similar to the one you are working with

```
df <- data.frame(species = sample(c('A', 'B', 'C'), 100, replace = T),
                 sex = sample(c('M', 'F'), 100, replace = T))
df
```

You can solve this problem using the dplyr package:

```
library(dplyr)

#create an auxiliar column to be summed
df$aux <- 1

#group by species and sex, summarise the groups by the sum of the auxiliar column
summary <- df %>%
  group_by(species, sex) %>%
  summarise(count_subjects = sum(aux))

summary
```

Comment: Thank you this gives me the reuslt I was looking for. A friend gave a a different solution using the tidyverse library that also worked. 

``install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)
MFspecies <- data%>%count(Species,Sex)
print(MFspecies)``

Answer (score 0):

Using base R you could do:

```r
set.seed(42)

data <- data.frame(
  Species = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 20),
  Sex = sample(c("m", "f"), 60, replace = TRUE)
)

data_split <- split(data, data$Species)
data_table <- lapply(data_split, function(x) table(x$Sex))
data_table <- do.call("rbind", data_table)
cbind(Species = rownames(data_table), as.data.frame(data_table))
#>   Species  f  m
#> A       A 11  9
#> B       B 12  8
#> C       C 10 10
```

or using`tapply` instead of `split + lapply`:

```r
data_table <- tapply(data$Sex, data$Species, table)
data_table <- do.call("rbind", data_table)
cbind(Species = rownames(data_table), as.data.frame(data_table))
#>   Species  f  m
#> A       A 11  9
#> B       B 12  8
#> C       C 10 10
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>